# Magnific Popup: opening second popup with different options

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Using Magnific Popup is it possible to force a second popup, opened while the first one is still open, to accept new options? The [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public_methods) states the following:

> "If popup is already opened - it'll just overwite the content (but old
>   options will be kept)."

I'm opening the popup using the public open() method within some JavaScript. The issue I have is that my first popup is modal so has no close button added to it. The second popup shouldn't be modal but because it uses the options of the first rather than it's own, it is modal.

Here's a jsFiddle with the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alangbuchanan/grx1ptcr/)

Here is an example:

**Html**

```
<div class="popup_dialog mfp-hide" id="modal_popup">
  <p>My modal popup</p>
</div>

<div class="popup_dialog mfp-hide" id="non_modal_popup">
  <p>My non modal popup, which should have a close button.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup_dialog {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.mfp-hide {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Open the first, modal popup
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: $('#modal_popup')
      },
      type: 'inline',
      modal: true
    });

    // Open the second, non-modal popup
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: $('#non_modal_popup')
        },
        type: 'inline',
        modal: false,
        closeBtnInside: true
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$.magnificPopup.close()` method before opening second popup, if you need it with different options.

Comment: I tried that but then the second pop up never opened. I'll try and reproduce on jsfiddle and update question. GREAT plugin by the way, thank you for creating it.

Comment: The reason the close method didn't work for me originally was because I had the removalDelay option set to 300. Presumably by the time the method was able to close the popup, the second one had already been added to the DOM and they were both removed.